# Web Essentials 2013 Less compile error

Tags: css, compiler-errors, less, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I searched for this problem but could not find a correct answer so here goes.
I'm coming from Visual Studio 2012 and Web Essentials 2012 and recently installed VS 2013 and WE 2013.

When compiling a .less file I get a error message in de .css preview pane

```
/*

Compile Error. 
See error list for details

*/
```

The error pane shows

```
LESS:
```

On Line1, Column 1

This happens with older and completely new projects.

I tried:

- Saving the .less file to UTF-8 without encoding
- Creating a new project with a less file with only one class
- Not using imports

Comment: Are you compiling it client-side with less.js or a serverside solution?

Comment: I'm using Web Essentials build in compiler (which uses less.js, I think). I switched back to WE 2012 due to multiple bugs. Haven't tested WE2013 for some time now..

Comment: Use Grunt.js to help you compile Less in Visual Studio

Comment: see: http://vswebessentials.com/features/less

Comment: You'll often see this error when you're missing something essential in the file for it to compile.  Could be a missed closing bracket.  Could be an unterminated string.  In my experience, the compiler fails with that cryptic message if the line its referencing is an empty line, so sometimes it helps to simply remove those from your LESS to debug these issues.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Off-course, this error will occurred if you add an **invalid css property** or **missed the semi-colon** or **brackets**. Check your CSS file. Provide the css code that you written.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it’s too late, but might help someone else.

I’ve had the same problem…
So annoying, and much time lost. I can’t tell you why, but VS 2013 works different when you use **.less** file.

Go to:

1. File -> New -> File
2. On left -> Select Web
3. Chose LESS style sheet
4. Cut and paste your code from old less

***First do this for your Styles.less (or however you call your ‘master’ less)**

It will compile every other after that.